# Building complex where statement in Laravel Eloquent using

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `Eloquent\Builder $query` that I want to use additional `where()` calls on, where the amount of the calls is indefinite and is taken from an array `$filter`, example below:

```
$filter = [
    'or:email:=:ivantalanov@tfwno.gf',
    [
        'or:api_token:=:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        'and:login:!=:administrator',
    ],
];
```

The strings, when parsed, produce valid SQL conditions, but the problem lies into sticking them into closures where a group is present (like strings 2 and 3 in the example - the array is their 'group').

I know of Laravel's functionality that allows sticking a `Closure` function into `$query->where()` to achieve what I want, but the problem I'm facing is actually building those complex closures. I have to iterate through every string in the group and pass it into the closure generated like so (where `$item` is the result of parsing a condition string):

```
$closure = function ($query) use ($item)
{
    call_user_func_array(
        [$query, $item['function']], [$item['field'], $item['operator'], $item['values']]
    );
};
```

Now the obvious problem with this is while it makes simple closures easily, passing more than one condition is plain impossible.
My question is, what could I use to prepare a complex statement to be executed on a query inside a closure?

Comment: Do you want something like in where clause: where ( a=1 and b=2) OR (c=2 and f=5)?

Comment: Yes, that's the gist of it.

Comment: I've answered. Please check and let me know if it is work for you. I'll help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured it out.

This is the method that will return the end result.

```
public function parse_filter(Builder &$query, array $filter)
{
    $groups = $this->_prepare_groups($filter);
    return $this->_parse_groups($query, $groups);
}
```

These methods will parse the initial array into something more usable.

```
private function _prepare_groups(array $filter)
{
    foreach ($filter as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            $groups[] = $this->_prepare_groups($item);
        }
        if (is_string($item)) {
            $simple_filter = $this->_parse_simple_filter($item);
            $groups[]      = $simple_filter;
            $simple_filter = null;
        }
    }

    return $groups;
}

private function _parse_simple_filter(string $filter)
{
    $filter_data = explode(':', $filter);

    $simple_filter['function'] = $filter_data[0] === 'and' ? 'where' : 'orWhere';
    $simple_filter['field']    = $filter_data[1];
    $simple_filter['operator'] = $filter_data[2];
    $simple_filter['values']   = $filter_data[3];

    return $simple_filter;
}
```

And here is where the most of the magic happens. Closures are recursive calls to this method, as you can see.

```
private function _parse_groups(Builder &$query, array $groups)
{
    foreach ($groups as $operator => $group) {
        if (!array_key_exists('function', $group)) {
            $closure = function ($query) use ($group)
            {
                $this->_parse_groups($query, $group);
            };
            $query->where($closure);
        } else {
            $query->{$group['function']}($group['field'], $group['operator'], $group['values']);
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Using this, you can modify an `Eloquent\Builder` object however you like with deeply nested filters that are declared dynamically (for example, received within a GET/POST request).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help for you:

In model create a scope:

```
public static function scopeGetResultList($query) {
     return $query->where(function ($query) use ($item) {
                  $query->where('group_user_holder_type', '=', 1)
                        ->orWhere('group_user_holder_type', '=', 0);
            });
}
```

> OR

Example:
    public static function getSearchedUserAuto($search_key, $user_id)
        {

```
        $users = DB::table((new User)->getTable().' as U')
                     ->select('U.*', 'CT.city_name', 'C.nicename')
                     ->leftJoin((new Country)->getTable().' as C', 'C.country_id', '=', 'U.user_country')
                     ->leftJoin((new City)->getTable().' as CT', 'CT.city_id', '=', 'U.user_city')
                     ->where(function($query) use ($search_key){
                            $query->where('U.user_full_name', 'like', '%'.$search_key.'%')
                                  ->orWhere('U.user_email', 'like', '%'.$search_key.'%');
                        })
                     ->where(function($query) use ($search_key){
                            $query->where('U.user_full_name', 'like', '%'.$search_key.'%')
                                  ->orWhere('U.user_email', 'like', '%'.$search_key.'%');
                        })
                     ->where('U.status', '=', 1)
                     ->where('U.user_id', '!=', $user_id)
                     ->get();


        return $users;
    }
```

See if it is work for you.

Comment: This isn't quite it, sorry. I am able to write the needed where chainings by hand, what I am looking for is some tips on how to make a method that would take in the initial query and an array of filter parameters and process it resulting in a new Eloquent\Builder object which had all the wheres applied to it.